# remove blank line at the end of a text file converted from an excel file

Tags: regex, text, notepad++, csv

So I have an excel table that I am converting to a tab delimited txt file. The only problem is that at the end of the converted file, there is a blank line. How can i get this to go away automatically?

Comment: Edit -> Line Operations -> Remove Empty Lines

Answer (score 0):

To remove the last *empty* lines you may use `\R+\z` regex and replace with nothing.

To remove the last *blank* line you may use `\R\h*\z` regex and replace with nothing.

Note that in general you may use

*Edit* -> *Line Operations* -> *Remove Empty Lines*

to remove all empty lines anywhere inside the file.

**NOTES on regex**:

- `\R` - matches a linebreak (CRLF, or CR, or LF)
- `\R+` - one or more linebreaks
- `\h*` - zero or more  (`*`) horizontal whitespaces
- `\z` - the very end of the file